# How do I stop HTML5 audio upon page refresh in Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, html5-audio, turbolinks

Within my Rails app, I have a view where, when you refresh the page, a new song plays.

When I manually refresh the page, the old song stops and a new song starts playing. But, in Firefox, when I click on a button inside the view to refresh the page, a new song starts playing, but the previous song keeps on playing. **How do I get this to work properly so that the previous song stops?**

It works in all browsers, except Firefox.

Here is what I have in my view:

```
<audio controls autoplay >
  <source src="<%= @song.mp3.url %>" type="audio/mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<%= link_to "Reload", url_for(params) %>
```

My gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

Comment: If this works with all browsers but Firefox, it doesn't sound like a Rails or Ruby question, it's HTML.

Comment: Any ideas? Do I have to write a JavaScript function to get the browser to stop playing the previous files? Isn't it supposed to automatically stop playing the old audio file when the page is refreshed? Could this be something to do with how firefox responds to turbolinks??

Comment: `turbolinks` <-- This is an important bit of information. Given that your "reload" link is just navigating to the same location, turbolinks is rebuilding the page on-the-fly via JS. **You are not actually refreshing the page.**

Comment: How do I get turbolinks to refresh the <audio></audio> part?

Comment: I don't know enough about your design to recommend a solution other than to disable turbolinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested and feels a little hacky, but should stop audio from playing when turbolinks loads a new page:

```
$(document).on('page:before-change', function(event) {
  $('audio').pause();
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried it and it didn't work :( Should I try stop instead of pause??

Comment: The `pause()` function comes from [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), which does not include a `stop()` function.  The `page:before-change` event was added in `turbolinks 1.3.0` - are you using `turbolinks >= 1.3.0`?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of turbolinks. I just edited my answer to show what I have in my gemfile.

Comment: Hmm... I'm out of guesses for now.  I can't reproduce this behavior with turbolinks 2.2.1 and Firefox 35.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is plainly related to how turbolinks work.
As of 2017 since `Turbolinks 5` was released, they changed available page events a little bit. [Here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/#full-list-of-events) you can find vast range of possibilities that we have now.

In order to stop previous audio playing you can use following code in proper *coffee* file:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:click', ->
  $('audio').remove(); //or just pause as previous person advised
```